# Sharepoint list Column with space in name not able to apply filter

Tags: c#, sharepoint, datatable

I am trying to achieve a filtering option on a SharePoint list that is retrieved as a data-table applying row-filter over the same (using the code snippet listed below).

**Code Snippet:**

```
dt.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("[Column name] = '{0}'",No.Text);
jView= dt.DefaultView;
gvViewJobs.DataSource = jView;
gvViewJobs.DataBind();
```

But when I execute the line on row filter getting the exception thrown as the 'column name' is not valid, also tried the option of using 'x0020' in the column name, even that is giving out the error. Also tried the below snippet of using filter option directly in datatable as shown below, but with no luck.

Datatable filtering

```
DataRow[] results = dt.Select("[column name] =' " + No.Text + "'");
```

Can anyone advise me of using referring the column name for filtering tried square bracket ([]) option too.

Regards
Arvind

Comment: Try with the internal name without square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Use a CAML builder to get the internal name of the field. Then ensure that you are using the appropriate expression for row filter.

Check [DataView RowFilter Syntax](http://www.csharp-examples.net/dataview-rowfilter/) for more details about the syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion had achieved the same by referring the datatable value using the column index instead of the column name.